# MongoDB merge queries as aggregated pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a two separated queries.

1. First one is to find removed items.
2. Second one is to check whether all items are removed on same country by itemId.

Can I merge it as pipeline?

Example Input:

```
itemId      removed     country
1           true        US
1           false       TR
2           true        US
2           true        RU
```

Example Output:

```
itemId: 2
```

Expected: (`itemId: 2`) Find itemIds that removed from all countries by itemId.

My code looks like:

```
db.collection.find({removed: true}, {itemId: 1}) -> Extract itemIdList

forEach id: itemIdList: [1, 2]
  if db.collection.find({removed: false, itemId: id}).count() > 0
     remove itemId from itemIdList
return remainingItems: [2];
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, your final goal is not clear here but from what I can see is that it can be achieved using $facet aggregate

Comment: Can you add an input example and expected output?

Comment: @AliHussam `$facet` only runs aggregation in parallel, meaning same set of documents are used as input and return the result for each aggregation separately, so you can not use that.

Comment: @OmarAbbas yes exactly, but as I mentioned the goal wasn't clear so I am not sure what can be done, thank you for mentioning this tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can achieve this by aggregate first group items by item id and counting total removed `true`, and total items. now in `$match` stage if the total number of items equals the removed true count that means, this `itemId` has `removed` `true` for all countries, and simply push the itemIds into an array.
[Working solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4zKBjeJt7c3)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$itemId",
            "itemsArrCount": {
                "$sum": 1
            },
            "totalRemovedTrue": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": ["$removed", true] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },        
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "$expr": {
                "$eq": [ "$itemsArrCount", "$totalRemovedTrue"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "itemIds": {
                "$push": "$_id"
            }
        }
    }
])
```